# Custom clang tool

Tags: c++, clang, llvm, llvm-clang

I am trying to get this custom clang tool to work. I can build it with no problem, but when I try to run it on simple example I get many errors regarding of `using`.

[image]

When I remove include (and printf) from test program I can run it with no problem. I am assuming that maybe I need compilation database of that file but I have no idea how to make one in code. Can someone help me and/or get me on right path? Example is from http://eli.thegreenplace.net. I am using latest clang and llvm along with VS 2012. For running the tool I am using command: `tool.exe test.c --` in tool's build directory.

Tool `tool.exe`:

```
#include <sstream>

#include "clang/AST/AST.h"
#include "clang/AST/ASTConsumer.h"
#include "clang/AST/RecursiveASTVisitor.h"
#include "clang/Frontend/ASTConsumers.h"
#include "clang/Frontend/FrontendActions.h"
#include "clang/Frontend/CompilerInstance.h"
#include "clang/Tooling/CommonOptionsParser.h"
#include "clang/Tooling/Tooling.h"
#include "clang/Rewrite/Core/Rewriter.h"
#include "llvm/Support/raw_ostream.h"

using namespace std;
using namespace clang;
using namespace clang::driver;
using namespace clang::tooling;

static llvm::cl::OptionCategory ToolingSampleCategory("Tooling Sample");

class MyASTVisitor : public RecursiveASTVisitor<MyASTVisitor> 
{
    public:
      MyASTVisitor(Rewriter &R) : TheRewriter(R) {}

      bool VisitStmt(Stmt *s) {
        if (isa<IfStmt>(s)) 
        {
          IfStmt *IfStatement = cast<IfStmt>(s);
          Stmt *Then = IfStatement->getThen();
          TheRewriter.InsertText(Then->getLocStart(), "// the 'if' part\n", true,
                                 true);

          Stmt *Else = IfStatement->getElse();
          if (Else)
            TheRewriter.InsertText(Else->getLocStart(), "// the 'else' part\n",
                                   true, true);
        }

        return true;
      }

      bool VisitFunctionDecl(FunctionDecl *f) {
        if (f->hasBody()) {
          Stmt *FuncBody = f->getBody();

          QualType QT = f->getReturnType();
          std::string TypeStr = QT.getAsString();

          DeclarationName DeclName = f->getNameInfo().getName();
          std::string FuncName = DeclName.getAsString();

          std::stringstream SSBefore;
          SSBefore << "// Begin function " << FuncName << " returning " << TypeStr
                   << "\n";
          SourceLocation ST = f->getSourceRange().getBegin();
          TheRewriter.InsertText(ST, SSBefore.str(), true, true);

          std::stringstream SSAfter;
          SSAfter << "\n// End function " << FuncName;
          ST = FuncBody->getLocEnd().getLocWithOffset(1);
          TheRewriter.InsertText(ST, SSAfter.str(), true, true);
        }

        return true;
      }

    private:
      Rewriter &TheRewriter;
};

class MyASTConsumer : public ASTConsumer 
{
    public:
      MyASTConsumer(Rewriter &R) : Visitor(R) {}

      bool HandleTopLevelDecl(DeclGroupRef DR) override {
        for (DeclGroupRef::iterator b = DR.begin(), e = DR.end(); b != e; ++b) {
          Visitor.TraverseDecl(*b);
          (*b)->dump();
        }
        return true;
      }

    private:
      MyASTVisitor Visitor;
};

class MyFrontendAction : public ASTFrontendAction 
{
    public:
      MyFrontendAction() {}
      void EndSourceFileAction() override {
        SourceManager &SM = TheRewriter.getSourceMgr();
        llvm::errs() << "** EndSourceFileAction for: "
                     << SM.getFileEntryForID(SM.getMainFileID())->getName() << "\n";

        TheRewriter.getEditBuffer(SM.getMainFileID()).write(llvm::outs());
      }

      std::unique_ptr<ASTConsumer> CreateASTConsumer(CompilerInstance &CI,
                                                     StringRef file) override {
        llvm::errs() << "** Creating AST consumer for: " << file << "\n";
        TheRewriter.setSourceMgr(CI.getSourceManager(), CI.getLangOpts());
        return llvm::make_unique<MyASTConsumer>(TheRewriter);
      }

    private:
      Rewriter TheRewriter;
};

int main(int argc, const char **argv) {
  CommonOptionsParser op(argc, argv, ToolingSampleCategory);
  ClangTool Tool(op.getCompilations(), op.getSourcePathList());
  Tool.run(newFrontendActionFactory<MyFrontendAction>().get());
  return 0;
}
```

Test program `test.c`:

```
#include <cstdio>

void foo(int* a, int *b) {
  if (a[0] > 1) {
    b[0] = 2;
    printf("%d", b[0]);
  }
}
```

Comment: `cstdio` is not a `C` header, use `#include <stdio.h>` if you want C and `cstdio` if you want C functionality in C++

Comment: That help, thank you. I missed that when I rewrited that file. You wanna post an answer so I could mark it as the right one?